# How do I set a breakpoint and step through R code that is sourced from Github

Tags: r

- I have an R library that I have installed from github using remotes::install_github.
- I have also downloaded the source code using git checkout
- When I call one of the library functions I'm getting an error (the parameters I'm using to connect to the database aren't working)

I am able to set a breakpoint in my code and step into the library code (sort of, I'm not able to set any break points in the library code and stepping seems to be approximate, I get the warning: "Debug location is approximate because the source is not available") by running the following code:

```
remotes::install_github("OHDSI/Strategus", ref="results-upload")
library(Strategus)


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DEBUG

debugExecute <- function() {
  Strategus::execute(
    analysisSpecifications = analysisSpecifications,
    executionSettings = executionSettings,
    executionScriptFolder = file.path(outputLocation, connectionDetailsReference, "strategusExecution"),
    keyringName = "sos-challenge"
  )
}

browser()
debugonce(debugExecute) 
debugExecute()
```

I would like to be able to set a break point in my calling code in RStudio and step into and set breakpoints in the library code.

How can I do this?

Comment: Since you said you cloned/downloaded the repo to a local directory, don't use `library(.)`, instead `devtools::load_all("path/to/local/Strategus")`, then you can debug the function and step through the actual source time. No need in this use-case for `install_github` or `library`.